# R: aggregate in data.table and reuse variable

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have a `data.table` that I want to summarize. It looks like that:

```
> DF
          new_src action
 1: cdn.adnxs.com      1
 2: cdn.adnxs.com      1
 3: cdn.adnxs.com      1
 4: cdn.adnxs.com      3
 5:   s1.2mdn.net      1
 6: cdn.adnxs.com      3
 7: cdn.adnxs.com      3
 8: cdn.adnxs.com      3
 9: cdn.adnxs.com      3
10: cdn.adnxs.com      3
```

I want to aggregate by `new_src`, find highest occurrence by `action`, calculate frequency, print this `action`, print total. 
I can do this in `ddply` using the `table` and reuse the variable within `ddply` so I don't need to run `table` multiple times. 
I need to do this in `data.table` but I cannot reuse the `table` results, I have to run `table` twice.

Example. This works:

```
DF = structure(list(new_src = c("cdn.adnxs.com", "cdn.adnxs.com", 
                                "cdn.adnxs.com", "cdn.adnxs.com", "s1.2mdn.net", "cdn.adnxs.com", 
                                "cdn.adnxs.com", "cdn.adnxs.com", "cdn.adnxs.com", "cdn.adnxs.com"), action = c("1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3")), .Names = c("new_src", "action"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

dt = DF[1:10,by=list(new_src),list(tb = sort(table(action),decreasing=T)[1], nm = names(sort(table(action),decreasing=T)[1]),tot = .N)]
View(dt)

ddpl = ddply(DF,.(new_src),summarize,tb = sort(table(action),decreasing=T)[1], nm = names(tb), tot = length(new_src))
View(ddpl)
```

This doesn't.

```
dt = DF[1:10,by=list(new_src),list(tb = sort(table(action),decreasing=T)[1], nm = names(tb),tot = .N)]
```

Is it possible with `data.table`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want `.N` here:

```
DF[, .N, by=.(new_src, action)][
  order(-N), .(topv = action[1], topn = N[1], n = sum(N)), by=new_src]

         new_src topv topn n
1: cdn.adnxs.com    3    6 9
2:   s1.2mdn.net    1    1 1
```

To handle ties, add more arguments to `order(-N, ...)`.

---

Instead of chaining the `by=`, nesting is another option:

```
DF[, .SD[, .N, by=action][order(-N), c(.SD[1], .(totn = sum(.N)))], by=new_src]

         new_src action N totn
1: cdn.adnxs.com      3 6    2
2:   s1.2mdn.net      1 1    1
```

I find it harder to follow, though; and it may be slower because [`j = .N` is optimized](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1251).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. That part of my code runs a whole lot faster now that I don't run `table` twice!